# Storing value temporary on text box, radio button or dropdown

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, textbox

It might be easy for someone else.. but is there a way to save the value(data) to the textbox temporary before submitting it?
So for example, 
let say there is shopping cart and user have to input their information right?
so i input my name and i will be like oh i forgot to add something and goes to different page to add more item to the shopping cart. And user comes back and will still have the data saved on the textbox.
I have been doing it and searching through google but could not solved it.

I would be really appreciated if someone can give me the logic of it.

Thank you

Comment: I believe you would need to attempt something before anybody would be willing to help

Comment: There are many ways to save user input; in memory, to a file, and to a database are probably the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

Most shopping carts will have a database behind them to save users carts. "How to write a database" is beyond the scope of this, though.

However, if you just want to store a few strings of information, localStorage is ideal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You can then implement events with JavaScript (or any JavaScript framework) to fire off after each change to the input, updating the localStorage object.

Here is an example implementation on a `<select>`:  [How to implement local storage on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407777/how-to-implement-local-storage-on-html).

This is one updating a shopping basket: [Implementing localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926278/implementing-localstorage)

But, there may be other options that fix your use case like IndexedDB (local storage for complex data) or simple use of the URL (fragment identifiers) as discussed in a great overview here: https://www.toptal.com/web/persisting-data-page-reloads-cookies-indexeddb

Comment: Hello Nathan, Thank you so much for your response to my question. I really appreciate it and i would take a look at each of your link.